# How to manipulate JComboBox - Java. (MouseListener)

Tags: java, combobox, mouselistener

`ComboBox cmbCategory, cmbType;`

I have two ComboBoxes. The 2nd `ComboBox` depends on the first `ComboBox`.

For example.
If I chose "Food" on cmbCategory, the choices on cmbType would be "desert, appetizer..")

How will I do that without clicking a button. I mean when "Food" is chosen on `cmbCategory`, the choices for food on `cmbType` would showed up automatically without clicking a button. Because what I have come up to is that my `cmbType` is hidden and when a button is clicked, then that's the time it will be visible.

I believe this is about `MouseListener` or `MouseClicked` but I have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: Please show some code!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ActionListener to the cmbCategory. On select call getSelectedItem() to get category.

Define a Map> the map should keep the list f items for each category. Fill the map (or you can define some logic to get list of types by selected category). Then just remove all the existing items in cmbType and add new list of types for the selected category.

See the ombobox related code snippets [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddItemstoJComboBox.htm)

Comment: I come up with this.

'if(obj==cmbItem){
                String item = cmbItem.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(item.equals(strItem[1])){
                    //I don't know what to put here.
                    
                }
                else if(item.equals(strCB)){
                    //Same with here
                }
            }'


Get the logic? That's what I wanted to happen with my program.